# Semantic UI icon white color not show

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I using [Semantic-UI](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/icon.html#icons) icons, in this case, I used group icon, and want to make a certificate icon with checked mark inside, it is good, but I want to make check icon white, but it's not working, I don't want to use additional `CSS` like color:white, I looking for semantic class, how can I do this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" integrity="sha256-9mbkOfVho3ZPXfM7W8sV2SndrGDuh7wuyLjtsWeTI1Q=" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<i class="huge icons">
  <i class="big blue certificate icon"></i>
  <i class="white check icon"></i>
</i>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `inverted` class

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" integrity="sha256-9mbkOfVho3ZPXfM7W8sV2SndrGDuh7wuyLjtsWeTI1Q=" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<i class="huge icons">
  <i class="big blue certificate icon"></i>
  <i class=" inverted check icon"></i>
</i>
```